# Multiple displays are glitched and overlapped when I connect to my M1 Mac using screen sharing or VNC apps on Mac, iOS or Linux

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, graphics, apple-silicon, screen-sharing

I have a 2015 MacBook Pro 15-inch with max specs and Radeon graphics.  For years I have been connecting 2 external displays to it. Most recently I  have a Dell S3422DWG which displays at 3440x1440 and a Dell S2721DGF which displays at 2560x1440 (in portrait mode).

When I’m out and I need to do some work from my iPhone or another laptop, I   connect through a screen sharing or VNC app on my phone or laptop and it works perfectly. I can see the 3 screens and move the mouse around.   This was my experience with my MacBook Pro 2015 15-inch using the screen-sharing / VNC server.

Now, fast forward to a few days ago, I just got an M1 Max 16-inch with 64GB RAM.

I was reading that it can support 4 external displays with no problem so I   figured mine would be no issue. I connected to my monitors using USB-C   (Thunderbolt 4) to DisplayPort cables. The resolution is correct on the screen, the refresh rates are maxed out and I also get HDR. There is nothing wrong with the cables.

However, the issue is when I connect to the laptop using a VNC or screen sharing clients, It is supposed to look like this

[image: Photo of monitor setup]

But what I get is this:

[image: Screenshot of monitor setup in the iOS app VNC Viewer]

This is a screenshot from my iOS app called VNC viewer.

As you can see with the M1 Max the screen are overlapping for some reason on the VNC client. I tried a few clients on my iOS, on my Windows PC,  my  Linux PC, and even on my old MacBook 2015. I still keep seeing the overlap. I made a view of it when I connected to my m1 max using my MacBook 2015 over on [my YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=guHZ7W9c1TU) you can see how glitchy it is on the overlapped section.

I have tried both the built-in app in macOS and other apps such as VNC viewer and VNC viewer. They all show the overlap.

As I said earlier, my Intel CPU 2015 MacBook Pro does not have this overlap. The screens are displayed perfectly.

I contacted tech support, and they asked me to unplug and replug, restart, go into Safe Mode, etc. it did not work.

For both my 2015 MacBook and M1 Mac, I am using the built-in screen sharing server made by Apple you can find in the **System Preferences** > **Sharing**.

[image: Screenshot of the Sharing Preferences window]

As for the mac screen share client, you can find it by typing screen sharing.app in spotlight. You can also try tight vnc on windows and vnc viewer on iOS to achieve similar results.

How can I get this work on the M1 as I was used to on the old Mac?

Comment: If you just use two monitors, does it work?

Comment: Yes if it’s just the internal and one external. Or both externals, or if I change the arranged to internal, s2721, s3422, the display doesn’t overlap. Also if I leave the arrangement as above and set the middle screen (s3422) as the main display there is no overlap.